# How can I fetch non-english column names from a table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have created an items_table. The columns' name of this table are ਸੋਯਾਬੀਨ and ਕਨ੍ਨੀ , which are in language other than english. I successfully created the columns using
alter table item_table add "+item.Text+" Nvarchar(50);

where the non-english column name was entered in a textbox on UI.
but now in next step i want to fetch the column names from this table and add them as an item in a combobox in a c# app. I want to know the query which can fetch the non-english column names. 
i am currently using the query-->>
select * from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where 
TABLE_NAME=N'item_table'

and what it returns is the name of my database.

Answer (score 1):

Based on little info you posted, I assume you're looking for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=N'MyTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of the rules but SQL Server requires you add additional encapsulation for non-English column names. It appears to be based on code page; I hope someone else can add a reference that's clearer.

This works on SQL Server 2008 (express):

SELECT [**वाabcÖ432ÖवाÖ**], [**[[]]न्यÖवा!223]]Ö**] FROM [dbo].[**वाabcÖ432ÖवाÖ**]

```
[ // Encapsulate the column
    [ // Escape the first set of characters
        [[]न्यÖवा!223]
    ]
    Ö
]
```